# Parsing boolean ListItem property into string

Tags: 2007, list, development

I am currently parsing boolean into string using this line, but it ain't working all of times, is there any alternative ?

```
bool.Parse(listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"].ToString()) == false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool? temp = listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"] as bool;
bool result = temp ?? true;
```

This code will read the property as a boolean, though return null if the property is null or not a bool (hence it is put into the [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) bool 'temp'). We then make it a normal bool use the ?? operator - if temp is null, result will be set to 'true'. Otherwise, result is set to whatever value temp has.

Using the '.Tostring()' risks a NullReferenceException if the property isn't set...

Comment: I was checking if property exists in code above using "ContainsField" but it was throwing exception for converting string into boolean but thanks anyway I give it a try, cheers

Comment: No problem, that's the pattern I use now, 'cos it avoids the .ToString (I did get caught but NullRef exceptions), and the same pattern works nicely with other types, such as ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
string valueS = "true";

Convert.ToBoolean(valueS);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd.aspx

hope it helps :)